# Using PyInstaller with Python 3.6

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to use PyInstaller. I had python 3.6 installed when I installed Pyinstaller. I then read that python 3.6 is not supported. So I downloaded python 3.5 as well. However, PyInstaller is still seeing python 3.6. How do I get it configured to the new (older) python? And (just out of interest) how do applications in general decide which python to use when there are multiple versions installed? Thanks.

Comment: It's generally the same on most OSes: the first executable named "python" it finds in your `PATH`. So see where it points to and change it. On Windows `SET PATH` will show it and on *nix `echo $PATH`.